# How can I show this jQuery animation in IE (7,8,9)?

Tags: jquery, css, cross-browser, jquery-animate

Thank you for looking at my question.

I have successfully integrated jCarousel with the Zoomer plugin (**[found here](http://addyosmani.com/blog/zoomer-gallery-a-jquery-plugin-for-displaying-images-with-flash-like-zooming-effects/)**).  It works EXACTLY the way I want it to in all browsers I have checked except **-SURPRISE!-** Internet Explorer...

If you check **[this page](http://www.remotereplacer.com/)** in FF, you'll see that the mouseover magnifies the blank white boxes, adds a red border and animates a little box with the alt attribute.

If you check the page again in IE, the magnify & red boxes work, but not the little box with the alt attribute.

I tried adding an IF to the head but I don't think it's working correctly (on OSX, so no IE).  Here is that code:

```
    <!--[if IE 9]>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    ul.thumb li img.hover
{
    border: 2px dotted red;
    border: none;
}
ul.thumb li .title
{
position:absolute;
width:103px;
height:40px;
margin:0px;
font-weight:900;
padding:0px 0 0 0px;
text-align:center;
color: #FFF;
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.9);
display: block;
}
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

I appreciate everyone's time and input.

Thank you!

Comment: What version of IE are we talking about?

Comment: My bad - IE 7, 8 & 9.  I'm expecting to be limited to 8 & 9, though.  I'll update the question.

Comment: I have discovered the fix for my first question; how to make it animate in IE.  i am going to edit the question to show only this one and give the answer, then ask a new one about the animation problem.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered through further research that the `rgba(#,#,#,#.#)` - the `a` stands for `ALPHA` and is a fancy way to control transparency, which does not work with IE.  I have changed the stylesheet to read as so for IE 8 & 9:

```
background-color: #FF0000;
filter:alpha(opacity=80); /* For IE8 and earlier */
opacity: 0.8;
```

I then changed the `IF` statement to address IE 6 compatibility to reflect the same code.